# Validate a field using another field

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-6

I have a dynamic phone number validation rule, and I need 2 values for it: `number` and `country`.

The library I'm using to validate the phone number is [brick/phonenumber](https://github.com/brick/phonenumber) which can include the country code to parse it accurately.

So, my current working approach looks like this:

```
$request->validate([
    'country' => ['required', 'max:2'],
]);

$request->validate([
    'number'  => ['required', new PhoneNumberValidator($request->input('country')],
]);
```

Because when I put it like this:

```
$request->validate([
    'country' => ['required', 'max:2'],
    'number'  => ['required', new PhoneNumberValidator($request->input('country'))],
]);
```

The `number` validation runs even if the `country` is not valid. So I'd like to know if there's a way to have all the validations in one `validate()` call, so, having the country value validated before calling the number rule (I tried with `bail` but that stops the validations for 1 attribute, not the rest of attributes in the queue).

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a custom rule](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) and validate both inputs at the same time.

You may also want to look at the various [validation rules.](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation) You might find something helpful.